# Centering text in buttons

Tags: android, text, center

I have problem with my text in buttons. Everything is fine when is app running on mobile with big screen. In order to see all components also on small screen I set up weight on my buttons and other components. After button compress the text isn't in center but on button(I guess compression cut vertical dimension from bottom.)

xml file:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/word_milk"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_cross"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cross_small"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_swarthy_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxHeight="45dp"
                android:onClick="B1Click"
                android:textColor="@color/Color_White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_word" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_swarthy_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxHeight="45dp"
                android:onClick="B2Click"
                android:textColor="@color/Color_White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_word" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_swarthy_green"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxHeight="45dp"
                android:onClick="B3Click"
                android:textColor="@color/Color_White"
                android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_word" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

screenshot: I set up text size 24sp on first button,26sp on second ,28sp on thirth with text "llllll" for better ilustration of behavior.

[image]

Thank you for help.

Comment: Could you update this question with your xml code, so that we can trace out the problem.

Comment: would also be nice for a screenshot , to see the problem itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that you didn't change the text size , so on other devices the text tries to fit on the button but it can't since the button is too small. if that's the case , set a different dimention for the text size depending on the screen .

however , since there is no code or screenshot here , i can't be sure if that's the case.

Comment: ok , i've looked at the xml , and found out that : 1.you forgot to set the height of the LinearLayout's children to 0px (since they have weight) . 2.you've set the text size based on the screen , but didn't handle the margins the same way .

Comment: Thank you I changed it, but the result is the same. Your second point is reasonable and I will remake it but It has nothing with button text position.

Comment: hmmm... have you tried using a 9-patch images for the background of the buttons? if so, have you set the content area correctly, so that it will be only in the center of the image?

Comment: You were right with your first post - it is in text size. But the behavior is strange! I update new image at my question.

Comment: i don't understand what is going on . now the images look even worse - they are not centered and there are weird lines-characters . what will happen if you use a TextView instead (just for testing) ? also , do you have the supports-screens tag in your manifest ?

Comment: I add supports-screens tag to manifest. It is still the same. I will use size which is not moveed down. It seems like there is some top margin and if text is too big the buttom move it down.

Comment: how did my answer help you if you still have the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14737/discussion-between-vlkpo-and-android-developer)

Answer (score 1):

set button property  android:gravity="center"
set property into java file also btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Comment: android:gravity="center" is already there and after adding code to java - no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try with padding hopes it will work for you ...

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_swarthy_green"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxHeight="45dp"
            android:onClick="B2Click"
            android:textColor="@color/Color_White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_word"

            // add padding here

            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"                 


/>
```

Comment: It move text down and cut the bottom margin so the text doesn't have down part.